# Not able to create core in solr using ubuntu terminal code

Tags: solr, drupal

Creating cores as the root user can cause Solr to fail and is not advisable. Exiting.
If you started Solr as root (not advisable either), force core creation by adding argument -force

sudo /opt/solr/bin/solr solr create_core -c sample_core

I tried to execute above code in my ubuntu terminal

Comment: I have some instructions here on how to install Solr on Ubuntu without using root: https://github.com/hectorcorrea/solr-for-newbies/wiki/Installing-Solr-on-Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Running Solr as root is not recommended for security reasons, and the `bin/solr start` command will refuse to do so. Consequently, you should determine the username of a system user that will own all of the Solr files and the running Solr process. By default, the installation script will create the solr user.

**Try this code as solr user like below**

```
sudo -u solr /opt/solr/bin/solr create_core -c sample_core -n data_driven_schema_configs
```